How to obtain custom estimated marginal means from `emmeans`?
Let's say that I have the following linear model of the mpg as a function of gear (3, 4, and 5) and vs (0 or 1):
mod <- lm(mpg  ~ factor(gear) * factor(vs), data = mtcars)

I know that I can obtain the marginal means of all the combinations of gear and vs with the emmeans function as such:
emm <- emmeans(mod, ~ gear * vs)
emm

#>  gear vs emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>     3  0   15.1 1.19 26     12.6     17.5
#>     4  0   21.0 2.92 26     15.0     27.0
#>     5  0   19.1 2.07 26     14.9     23.4
#>     3  1   20.3 2.39 26     15.4     25.2
#>     4  1   25.2 1.31 26     22.6     27.9
#>     5  1   30.4 4.13 26     21.9     38.9
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

However, if I want to obtain the marginal mean of the custom group with gear 3 and gear 4, how can I do that with emmeans ?
I know that to obtain a custom contrast, I can specify the constrast vector as such:
contrast(
  emm, 
  method = list(
    "gear 3-4" = c(-0.5, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0)
    "gear 5" = c(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1)
  )
)

#>  contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  gear 3-4     4.76 2.08 26   2.285  0.0307
#>  gear 5      11.28 4.62 26   2.440  0.0218

Is there a way to do something similar with marginal means instead of contrasts ?

I'm not sure what you're asking. Marginal means is dependent on the bigger picture. If you wanted to know the marginal means of a subset, it's based on the model of that subset. Marginal means is essentially how well the data fits the model by using model-based predictions.

This is done using the add_grouping() function:
> emm2 <- add_grouping(emm, "custom", "gear", c("grp34", "grp34", "other"))
> emmeans(emm2, "custom")

custom emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 grp34    20.4 1.04 26     18.3     22.5
 other    24.8 2.31 26     20.0     29.5

Results are averaged over the levels of: gear, vs 
Confidence level used: 0.95 


Amazing, this is just what I was looking for. Thank you !
